# При импорте в Magento 2 через Magmi на каждый товар выпадают лишние изображения. Как это можно исправить?

Tags: magento

Есть исходный CSV-файл для импорта товаров с категориями. В нем прописаны ссылки на изображения с другого ресурса. При импорте товары, категории импортируются нормально, так же импортируются изображения с другого сервера по ссылкам. На каждый товар приходится по одному соответствующему ему изображению. Но при проверке оказывается что у каждого товара помимо этих фотографий примешаны по 2-3 лишних фото от других товаров. Колонка additional_images - пустая. Чистил кэш, удалял перед импортом все в /pub/media/catalog/product, так же сносил в БД таблицы с товарами и категориями - не помогает. Так же попробовал все изображения из исходного проекта вручную перенести на разрабатываемый. Причина так и осталась не ясной. Привожу часть исходного CSV-файла как пример:

```
"sku","store","store_view_code","attribute_set","attribute_set_code","product_type","categories","product_websites","name","description","short_description","weight","status","tax_class_name","visibility","price","special_price","special_price_from_date","special_price_to_date","url_key","meta_title","meta_keywords","meta_description","image","image_label","small_image","small_image_label","thumbnail","thumbnail_label","swatch_image","swatch_image_label","created_at","updated_at","new_from_date","new_to_date","display_product_options_in","map_price","msrp_price","map_enabled","gift_message_available","custom_design","custom_design_from","custom_design_to","custom_layout_update","page_layout","product_options_container","msrp_display_actual_price_type","country_of_manufacture","additional_attributes","qty","out_of_stock_qty","use_config_min_qty","is_qty_decimal","allow_backorders","use_config_backorders","min_cart_qty","use_config_min_sale_qty","max_cart_qty","use_config_max_sale_qty","is_in_stock","notify_on_stock_below","use_config_notify_stock_qty","manage_stock","use_config_manage_stock","use_config_qty_increments","qty_increments","use_config_enable_qty_inc","enable_qty_increments","is_decimal_divided","website_id","related_skus","related_position","crosssell_skus","crosssell_position","upsell_skus","upsell_position","additional_images","additional_image_labels","hide_from_product_page","custom_options","bundle_price_type","bundle_sku_type","bundle_price_view","bundle_weight_type","bundle_values","bundle_shipment_type","configurable_variations","configurable_variation_labels","associated_skus"
"N/A:0000-4","en","","Default","default","simple","Toys/Action figures & Toys;;Toys/Dolls & Accessories ;;/4-7 years;;Toys/Action figures & Toys/Gifts set","","Our Generation Hair Grow Doll Brunette Parker","<p>She is Brunette Parker. She is cool, she is cute and she has lovely long hair. Try all your hair styling tricks on Brunette. She will loves to take care of her. She is ever willing to be the show stopper wherever she goes. This set includes:1 hair play doll, 1 dress, 1 headband with flower, 1 crochet vest, 1 belt, 1 pair of undies, 1 pair of shoes, 1 comb, 2 hair extensions, 2 metal heart clips, and 1 hair style guide booklet.</p>","","",2,"","Catalog, Search",239.0,0,"","","","","","","uploads/posts/2017/07/0062243253100-a.jpg","","uploads/posts/2017/07/0062243253100-a.jpg","","uploads/posts/2017/07/0062243253100-a.jpg","","","","2017-07-17 17:30:04","2017-07-17 17:30:04","","","Block after Info Column","","","","","","","","","","","","","",10,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,"",1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,"","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""
"N/A:0000-4","ru","","Default","default","simple","Toys/Action figures & Toys;;Toys/Dolls & Accessories ;;/4-7 years;;Toys/Action figures & Toys/Gifts set","","Our Generation Hair Grow Doll Brunette Parker","<p>Она брюнетка Паркер. Она классная, она милая, и у нее прекрасные длинные волосы. Попробуйте все ваши трюки для волос на брюнетке. Ваша маленькая дeвочка будет любить её заботиться о ней. Она всегда готова быть шоу-стоптером, куда бы она ни отправилась. Этот комплект включает в себя: 1 кукла для игры в игрушки, 1 платье, 1 головной убор с цветком, 1 вязание крючком, 1 пояс, 1 пара неувядающих, 1 пара обуви, 1 расческа, 2 наращивания волос, 2 металлических клипа для сердца и 1 прическа путеводитель.</p>","","",2,"","Catalog, Search",239.0,0,"","","","","","","uploads/posts/2017/07/0062243253100-a.jpg","","uploads/posts/2017/07/0062243253100-a.jpg","","uploads/posts/2017/07/0062243253100-a.jpg","","","","2017-07-17 17:30:04","2017-07-17 17:30:04","","","Block after Info Column","","","","","","","","","","","","","",10,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,"",1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,"","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""
"5702015868303","en","","Default","default","simple","Toys;;Toys/Vehicles ;;Toys/Constructions;;Brand;;Brand/Disney;;Toys/Action figures & Toys;;Toys/Action figures & Toys/Play sets;;Toys/Vehicles /Model vehicles ;;/4-7 years","","LEGO Juniors Mater`s Junkyard","<p>A merry set of LEGO Juniors is sure to appeal to the small fans of Disney Cars. The set includes 62 design elements, printed assembly instruction. The designer is one of the most fascinating and fun ways to spend time. The child can spend hours playing with the designer, coming up with different situations and stories.</p>","","",1,"","Catalog, Search",27.0,0,"","","","","","","uploads/posts/2018/02/lego-10733-mater-s-junkyard.jpg","","uploads/posts/2018/02/lego-10733-mater-s-junkyard.jpg","","uploads/posts/2018/02/lego-10733-mater-s-junkyard.jpg","","","","2018-02-20 13:30:42","2018-02-20 13:30:42","","","Block after Info Column","","","","","","","","","","","","","",8,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,"",1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,"","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""
"5702015868303","ru","","Default","default","simple","Toys;;Toys/Vehicles ;;Toys/Constructions;;Brand;;Brand/Disney;;Toys/Action figures & Toys;;Toys/Action figures & Toys/Play sets;;Toys/Vehicles /Model vehicles ;;/4-7 years","","LEGO Juniors  Свалка Мэтра ","<p>Весёлый набор LEGO Juniors обязательно понравится маленьким фанатам Disney Cars. В набор входят 62 элементов конструктора, печатная инструкция по сборке. Конструктор - это один из самых увлекательных и веселых способов времяпрепровождения. Ребенок сможет часами играть с конструктором, придумывая различные ситуации и истории.</p>","","",1,"","Catalog, Search",27.0,0,"","","","","","","uploads/posts/2018/02/lego-10733-mater-s-junkyard.jpg","","uploads/posts/2018/02/lego-10733-mater-s-junkyard.jpg","","uploads/posts/2018/02/lego-10733-mater-s-junkyard.jpg","","","","2018-02-20 13:30:42","2018-02-20 13:30:42","","","Block after Info Column","","","","","","","","","","","","","",8,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,"",1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,"","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","","",""
```

- Версия Magento: 2.2.6
- Версия Magmi: v0.7.23-git (https://github.com/macopedia/magmi-m2)
- Версия Apache: 2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
- Версия MySQL: Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.24
- Версия PHP: v7.0.32

Может кто сталкивался с этим?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем никто не ответил, а тем временем я нашел причину. Оказывается после импорта я очищал таблицы в БД, но при этом не очищал через `TRUNCATE` таблицу `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value_to_entity`. Так вот, в этой таблице все привязки изображений к товарам сохранялись, и после каждого импорта перемешивались. Очистить таблицу можно также через phpMyAdmin. Надеюсь кому-то помог кроме себя.